# How to fetch limited result set from redis database

Tags: python, redis

I am building a web app in CherryPy with redis as main database, right now I have lot of key values stored in database and I want to display only 10 entries per page. So I just want to know to use `sql limit` or `redis scan`in this situation.

```
import redis
import json
import cherrypy
from controllers.base import BaseController

con = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=3)

class HomeController(BaseController):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        outdata = []
        keys = con.keys()
        for key in keys:
            dt = con.get(key)
            dat = dt.decode('utf-8')
            res = json.loads(dat)
            outdata.append(res)
        return self.render_template('home/index.html', {'outdata' : outdata})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of two functions in the redis-py library, [scan_itr](http://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.scan_iter) or [scan](http://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.scan) (part of the `StrictRedis` not `Redis` class your code snippet is using).

It's important to notice that scan doesn't guarantee items won't show up again or new keys will be returned as you scan. Take a look at the official documentation for more [info](https://redis.io/commands/scan#scan-guarantees).